# Textarea is not showing in php. What is error?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have following script to print a textarea and some text into that. When page is loaded, textarea does not appear even when while condition is true. What could be the problem?

```
$seq_query = "SELECT * FROM `mcsm`.`conseq_human` WHERE `MCSM_Id`='$mcsm_id';";
$seq_result = mysql_query($seq_query);

print '<table border="0" align="left" style="margin-left:207px"><tr><th align="left">Conserved sequence</th></tr>';

if(!$conseq = mysql_fetch_array($seq_result))
{
    print "<tr><td><p>Not sufficient information yet.</p></td></tr></table>";
}
else
{
    while($conseq = mysql_fetch_array($seq_result))
    {
        print "<tr><td><textarea name='seq_textarea' cols='100' rows=''>".$conseq['ConSequence']."</textarea></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Based on MSA of ".$conseq['MSA_No_of_Seq']." sequences from <a href='results1.php?category=".$conseq['FamilyName']."' target='_self'>".$conseq['FamilyName']."</a> family.</td></tr></table>";
    }
}
```

Comment: have `rows=''` to `rows='6'`

Comment: @FahimParkar   This is not working

Comment: type `echo "test"` before print and see you are getting that text or not... may be condition itself is not going there. may be you dnt have data in mysql result.

Comment: @FahimParkar   Didn't worked. I typed echo "test" inside while loop.

Comment: @majidgeek : see or show?

Comment: @HarishPareek : Means you don't have data in mysql query result. try yadav answer. Either your query is wrong or data is not there with respective query

Comment: @FahimParkar show!!! please

Comment: @HarishPareek : I believe Chetan answer must have helped you. Could you please mark the answer as accepted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
$seq_query = "SELECT * FROM `mcsm`.`conseq_human` WHERE `MCSM_Id`='$mcsm_id';";
$seq_result = mysql_query($seq_query);
print '<table border="0" align="left" style="margin-left:207px"><tr><th align="left">Conserved sequence</th></tr>';
if(mysql_num_rows($seq_result)>0)
{
    while($conseq = mysql_fetch_array($seq_result))
   {
    print "<tr><td><textarea name='seq_textarea' cols='100'        rows=''>".$conseq['ConSequence']."</textarea></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Based on MSA of ".$conseq['MSA_No_of_Seq']." sequences from <a href='results1.php?category=".$conseq['FamilyName']."' target='_self'>".$conseq['FamilyName']."</a> family.</td></tr></table>";
   }
}
else{
print "<tr><td><p>Not sufficient information yet.</p></td></tr></table>";
}
```

Comment: I think you should write `rows=''` to `rows='6'`, else multi-line data will be shown in one line only.

Comment: @FahimParkar i just want to say him that use mysql_fetch_array() once and for checking morethan records fetched or not for that should use mysql_num_rows()

Comment: @Yadav Chetan  Thanks bro! I'm shocked, how I didn't got it first.

Comment: @HarishPareek you'r welcome keep going and read some basic fundamental of php function so that you can get more idea

Comment: @YadavChetan : Yes, I got that point. But what OP will do is COPY your code and paste it. Hence its good habit to clean other wrong code also. Hence I mentioned that. That's it. +1

Answer (score 0):

You are printing `</table>` for each `while` iteration.try this:

```
$seq_query = "SELECT * FROM `mcsm`.`conseq_human` WHERE `MCSM_Id`='$mcsm_id';";
$seq_result = mysql_query($seq_query);
if (!$seq_result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
else{
    print '<table border="0" align="left" style="margin-left:207px"><tr><th align="left">Conserved sequence</th></tr>';
    if(mysql_num_rows($seq_result)==0)
    {
        print "<tr><td><p>Not sufficient information yet.</p></td></tr></table>";
    }
    else
    {
        while($conseq = mysql_fetch_array($seq_result))
        {
            print "<tr><td><textarea name='seq_textarea' cols='100' rows=''>".$conseq['ConSequence']."</textarea></td></tr>
                   <tr><td>Based on MSA of ".$conseq['MSA_No_of_Seq']." sequences from <a href='results1.php?category=".$conseq['FamilyName']."' target='_self'>".$conseq['FamilyName']."</a> family.</td></tr>";
        }
        echo '</table>';
    }
}
```